# как спарсить содержимое, или весь JS скрипт целиком?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, curl, simple-html-dom

у меня есть парсер через curl_get и библиотеку simple_html_dom
мне надо получить содержимое JS скрипта или весь скрипт, но когда я его получаю, такое чувство что он читает и записывает в одну строчку, в скрипте есть Коментарии и на выходе я получаю закометрированый непонятный без пробелов и отступов код который не годится.

```
include_once('curl_query.php');
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = curl_get("https://site.com");
$html= iconv("Windows-1251", "utf-8", $html);
$dom = str_get_html($html);
$courses = $dom->find("#d-cot .seson .boxi_navi script");
$d = $courses[2]->innertext;
echo $html;
```

Comment: может вы получаете `min.js`?

Comment: Кажется, вам нужно еще взять ссылку из src этого скрипта и повторить запрос с новым урлом

Comment: это просто скрипт без подключения, но просто вести на странице, если прописать  в этом же коде echo $html; то выведется страница вся, но это скрипт будет лежать и он будет нормальный